# Broken links starting with http://%20https://

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, https

An edit suggestion [like this](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/978255) pretty often appears in the review queue.
[image]

These edits are generally fixing `http://%20https://` to `https://`. (`%20` means an escaped space in URLs.)

Does anyone know why such broken links appear so often? Shouldn’t they be corrected automatically?

Comment: Related on [meta.se]: [What causes “http://%20https://” links to be made?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337401/what-causes-http-20https-links-to-be-made)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks! [The answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337404/217657) makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by copying a link with a preceding space into the Insert Hyperlink dialog. The software adds `http://` in front of it and a broken link starting with `http://%20https://` is born.

See [What causes “http://%20https://” links to be made? on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337401/what-causes-http-20https-links-to-be-made/337404#337404) for details.

Answer (score 8):

I reckon this happens sometimes while adding a link using the "insert hyperlink" tool (either by clicking the button or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) instead of using Markdown.

The input box contains `https://` (which is selected) by default
[image]
(and I believe it used to have `http://` by default previously). So usually while pasting the link, it overwrites the `https://` with the copied link. But it seems sometimes the default text (inadvertently) gets deselected and a space is added, and then the copied link gets appended.

Comment: I’d guess something like this but the question I mentioned was asked in January 2019. I am pretty sure the SE’s transition to HTTPS had happened before… See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296276/217657, for example.

Comment: That's strange! Any chance that's a (at least partially) copy-pasted (from an older post) question?

Comment: @Melebius Also the Meta Stack Exchange answer you linked in your previous comment is about the "sharing links" for posts, I don't think  this applies to the current issue. I think in this case, switch to https took place with the [editor improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576) (last October-November). Although the point you raised is still valid as the question in question was asked last January.